# SQL query, view joined to table - number of results inconsistent

Tags: sql-server-2000

Apologies in advance for the vagueness of this question, but it involves a query which is too big to describe in full, and field/table names that I can't reveal. So I'm not really expecting a solution, but if someone give some advice on how I could proceed in solving it myself, I'd be grateful.

SQL Server 2000.

I have a query which joins a view and a table with an INNER JOIN and has a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT
  view.join_field
FROM
  view INNER JOIN table ON view.join_field=table.join_field
WHERE
  table.other_field='EE'

# (23 rows)
```

This produces 23 results (it should be 1000s). If I add another WHERE clause to the above query, I get *more* results, instead of less:

```
SELECT
  view.join_field
FROM
  view INNER JOIN table ON view.join_field=table.join_field
WHERE
  table.other_field='EE' AND
  view.field2=1
```

This gives me a few thousand results, as was originally expected. Changing the value to 2 or 3 (the only other values present) also gives me thousands of results each, but if I change it to `view.field2 IN (1,2,3)` I end up with only 38 results.

Going back to the original query, which gave me 23 results, if I add the *table* field I have in the WHERE clause to the SELECT block, I get the right number of results:

```
SELECT
  view.join_field,
  table.other_field
FROM
  view INNER JOIN table ON view.join_field=table.join_field
WHERE
  table.other_field='EE'

# (8764 rows)
```

If I instead use a WHERE clause of `table.other_field='GG'` (the only other value present in the table), none of these strange things happen, and I get the expected number of results.

If I SELECT the contents of *view* into a temporary table, and use that in my query, I also get the thousands of rows I was expecting.

*view* itself is an LEFT OUTER JOIN of another view and two other tables. *table*, in my query, is not involved in any of the views.

Can anyone give me even the vaguest of ideas of what's going on? Are my tables or views corrupt, somehow?

Comment: In your first example, instead of joining to the view, can you wrap the view as a sub select alias it and see if you get more than 23 that way?  Example: `SELECT
  v.join_field
FROM (View Source SQL) v INNER JOIN table ON v.join_field=table.join_field
WHERE
  table.other_field='EE'`  Honestly it seems like a possible index is corrupt on a table you may need to drop and re-create indexes on the tables involved.  Is this a materialized view?

Comment: That didn't seem to make any difference - I still get a low number of results (33 now, but some of the tables used in the view have had their data deleted and re-imported overnight). I've tried deleting and recreating what indexes I can to no effect. I'll go with selecting into a #temporary table for now.

Comment: Probably a service pack issue, check so you have the latest SP 4